# How do I configure NiFi to handle a date format when using the PutQueryRecord

Tags: oracle, apache-nifi

*This is a bit challenging to post this question because on this computer that I'm submitting this post on does not have NiFi installed on it.*

**Error:** oracle 01830 date format picture ends before converting entire input string

In the flowfile content a date value: e.g.: **"lastDate", "19-Apr-2023 07:13:28"**

There is a PutDatabaseRecord that is in the Flow that is

1. Performing an INSERT
2. Uses a JsonTreeReader
3. #2 uses a Schema Registry type "AvroSchemaRegistry"
4. The #3 registry contains an entry for: "lastDate", "type": "string"

Now, with the date value as described above the ORA 01830 occurs.

If I strip the time off then it will work. I need the time but don't know this mapping stuff and don't know how to correct the issue.

When I do anything with databases I prefer to write out the SQL but being that this massive flow I'm told to fix is like dominos I'm trying to avoid changing much in it.

So, what should I be looking for or need to add to this flow to get past the PutDatabaseRecord issue?

**Note about Oracle**
The oracle equivalent of what I verified in SQL Developer is
e.g.

```
UPDATE SOME_DB
SET SOME_DATECOLUMN = TO_DATE('19-Apr-2023 07:13:28', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh:mi:ss')
WHERE SOME_COL=1;
```

Comment: could you check if oracle supports auto-conversion from `'2023-04-19 07:13:28'` ansi sql formatted string to a datetime - try to insert this string value into a datetime column. if yes - then just convert format this one before executing PutQueryRecord.

Comment: Either convert the value to date using `UpdateRecord` processor or set [`sql.args.N.format`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL/) parameter of the flow file